# Is it possible to import functions in a class, to improve readability?

Tags: function, class, python-import, readability

I've created several iterable classes. The code to provide these iterable properties is repetitive throughout each of the classes and clutters the code, distracting from the class unique functions.

I'm talking about having to write down `__iter__`, `__next__`, `__getitem__`,`__setitem__`, `__len__`, and `append` functions, the same way for each of my classes (see image below).

Is there any way to just write this down once, and import it in my class?

If this seems a too basic question, I promise I tried to work my way through the search results, but they landed me many different types of imports, function and class usage, without answering my question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned the solution to this problem as I learnt more about [inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php):

So the solution would be inherit to start with:

```
class Samples(list):
    ...
```